# Is it on-topic to ask about something based on a game?

Tags: support, scope

Could I ask a question, for instance, about the *Super Mario Bros.*-based cartoons or *Dishonored* books here?

Answer (score 4):

If your question is specifically about books and/or cartoons of a game **you shouldn't ask here**.

We are primarily focused on playing games and while there are certainly some people on the site who are familiar with the "extended universe" of the games they're playing it's not really our expertise.

We can help with lore related questions **if the information is available in-game**.

For any questions regarding books or comics you should try out either [scifi.se](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [literature.se](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).

If you have questions about a series or movie about a game you could check out [movies.se](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Just make sure to read their FAQ before posting a question but those things should be on-topic.

Again as I've said there are a lot of people interested in the extended universe of games on arqade and fortunately we do have a chatroom where we can discuss things like that. So if you just want to chat and discuss some topics about game related media feel free to join us in [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) or you could even create your own chatroom.